# Adding a class on the buttons of my jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery dialog:

```
    // Configure buttons
    var dialogButtons = {};

    dialogButtons[buttonConfirm] = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) { var func = success; window[func](data); }
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    dialogButtons[buttonCancel] = function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    // Configure dialog
    $dialog.dialog(
        {
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: dialogButtons
        });

    // Opening dialog
    $dialog.dialog('open');
```

**My question**: I would like to set a specific class 'btn' on my buttons. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to add the buttons a class? use their class (`ui-button`) You should avoid wheel reinvention...

Comment: I have a specific CSS file with standard look'n feel for all my tables, buttons, ... When adding the class btn or primary or ... on my buttons (anywhere) I am able to change color for primary, and some other cool stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Colin had one answer, but I thought I'd be more specific to the dialog in question. jQuery-UI has a `widget` method that returns the elements that are comprised of the dialog itself. Coupling this with locating `ui-button` class, you can get what you're looking for:

```
$dialog.dialog('widget') // Grab widget (UI element)
  .find('.ui-button')    // Locate buttons within
  .addClass('btn');      // hadd btn class to them
```

EDIT: Also, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8WckB/

Answer (score 1):

```
// Configure dialog
$dialog.dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: dialogButtons,
    open: function(e, ui) { 
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset"); // here is your 
                                                                    // button container
        $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button").addClass("btn"); // whereas this would select
                                                                                               // all buttons in button container
        // you could even use the widget method
        // $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source, in the method `_createButtons` of `jquery.ui.dialog.js` you'll see that the hash that is indexed by the text of the button is treated as a collection of properties if it is not a function. So you can do the following:

```
var $dlg = $('#dlg').dialog({
    buttons: {
        'firstButton': {            
            'click': function() {
                $dlg.dialog('close');
            },
            'text' : 'OK',         
            'class': 'myclass'
        },
        'Cancel': function(){
            $dlg.dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a fork of Brad's fiddle demonstrating the code http://jsfiddle.net/uWnpy/